# How to generate Duty Cycle from DC without 555

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, duty-cycle

I am currently working on a simple circuit which includes creating duty cycle from DC. Also, I need to change it's pulse width with time. I have decided to use op-amp relaxation oscillator to produce square waves but I have no idea how to chance it's width. I am allowed to use resistors, capacitors, inductors, diodes, OPAPs, transistors and relays.

[image]

My question is how can I create a circuit which produces duty cycle and it's pulse width is changing with time as shown at the picture above.

Comment: Not that your question isn't perfectly valid, but why in the world would you eliminate the IC that's probably most suitable for this task?

Comment: Because that's what his homework says :P

Comment: Just design it with a 555, then delete the 555 and replace it with the 555's internal schematic :D

Comment: Look at a 555 equivalent diagram and see how it achieves duty cycle control using a two level comparator and charge and discharge circuitry. Go and do functionally likewise. That's the other end of the approach that Majenko suggests - destination should be the ame.

Comment: @Majeko is right that's my homework's restriction

Comment: Try with old fashion Unijunction transistors (UJTs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the relaxation oscillator to make a ramp or triangle wave and then compare that wave's voltage to a DC voltage that you can control (for example with a potentiometer).